# Static libpixman-1.a Linking Errors on Windows

Tags: c, cairo, pixman

I am trying to build a static [Cairo library](https://www.cairographics.org/) on Windows under [MSYS2/MinGW-w64](https://www.msys2.org/) & am having trouble linking to `libpixman-1.a` static library. The linker errors are as follows:

```
...
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/libcairoboilerplate.a
C:/Development/MSYS2/mingw32/lib/libpixman-1.a(pixman-x86.c.obj):(.text+0x204): undefined reference to `_pixman_implementation_create_mmx'
C:/Development/MSYS2/mingw32/lib/libpixman-1.a(pixman-x86.c.obj):(.text+0x213): undefined reference to `_pixman_implementation_create_sse2'
C:/Development/MSYS2/mingw32/lib/libpixman-1.a(pixman-x86.c.obj):(.text+0x1b8): undefined reference to `_pixman_implementation_create_ssse3'
```

The issue appears to be directly related to the `libpixman-1.a` library itself. I've searched the web but have not found any issues concerning the undefined references mentioned above. I have sent messages to [Cairo](https://lists.cairographics.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/cairo) & [Pixman](https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/pixman) mailing lists, as the two projects appear to be related. I have also contacted the Cairo project on [their IRC channel](https://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=#cairo). I am currently still waiting on responses. I have also sent an issue report to the MSYS2 project.

The following is the configuration command that I used for building the static `libpixman-1.a` library (which uses the [Meson Build system](https://mesonbuild.com/) of which I am not very familiar):

```
meson --buildtype plain -Ddefault_library=static -Dgtk=disabled ../pixman-0.38.4
```

MSYS2 uses a port of [Arch Linux's build system](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Build_System) for its package management. The original build configuration & patches for the pixman library can be [found here](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/blob/b80713152cedea8f421b4428c973b9f584734f63/mingw-w64-pixman).

Next is the configuration that I am trying to use for building a static cairo library:

```
CFLAGS+=" -Wno-implicit-function-declaration"
../cairo-1.16.0/configure --prefix=/mingw32 \
    --build=x86_64-pc-mingw32 --host=x86_64-pc-mingw32 --enable-win32 --enable-win32-font \
    --enable-png --enable-shared=no --enable-static --enable-gobject --enable-tee \
    --disable-xlib --disable-xcb --enable-fc --enable-ft --disable-silent-rules \
    LIBS="-lharfbuzz -lbz2" ac_cv_prog_GS=${MINGW_PREFIX}/bin/gsc
```

The original build configuration & patches for the cairo library can be [found here](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/blob/b80713152cedea8f421b4428c973b9f584734f63/mingw-w64-cairo).

Originally I was also getting undefined references for [harfbuzz](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/HarfBuzz/) & [bzip2](http://www.bzip.org/) libraries. But adding explicit links to them (`LIBS="-lharfbuzz -lbz2"`) solved those issues. Since the linker is already trying to link to `libpixman-1.a` library, including it in the `LIBS` variable does not change anything.  And because there is no shared pixman library on my system, using an explicit static link (`-l:libpixman-1.a`) doesn't help either. I believe I attempted that already, but will try again, just in case.

**Edit:** I found the options `-Dmmx=disabled -Dsse2=disabled -Dssse3=disabled` for building the pixman library & going to try rebuilding. Perhaps those options are only available in the shared version of the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building pixman library with MMX, SSE2, & SSSE3 optimizations disabled fixes the problem & allows me to build static only cairo library:

```
meson --buildtype plain -Ddefault_library=static -Dgtk=disabled -Dmmx=disabled -Dsse2=disabled \
    -Dssse3=disabled ../pixman-0.38.4
```